# Maximum principle for a fractional Laplacian operator

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

Let $\Omega=\{x\in \mathbb R^N: R_1<|x|<R_2\}$ be a bounded in $\mathbb R^N$ and $N>2s$ with $s\in (0, 1)$.
If $u$ is a smooth solution to the problem $(-\Delta)^su=0$ in $\Omega$ with $u=f$ in $|x|<R_1$ and $u=h$ in $|x|>R_2.$ Is it possible to deduce a maximum principle for $u$ provided $f, g$ are bounded functions in $\mathbb{R}^N.$

Comment: Given, say, boundedness of $u$ near the boundary, this follows by standard arguments. In fact, $u$ is given as an integral of $h$ with respect to an appropriate (sub-probabilistic) harmonic measure. I bet one can find it in Landkoff or Bliedtner–Hansen (although in a different language). You may also like a [paper](http://pldml.icm.edu.pl/pldml/element/bwmeta1.element.bwnjournal-article-smv133i1p53bwm) by Bogdan and Byczkowski titled "Potential theory for the $\alpha$-stable Schrödinger operator on bounded Lipschitz domains".